# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' on line 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a complete newbie programmer, infact I just started today.. I was trying to follow a basic guide on how to calculate gross pay and I keep coming up with the following error "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' on line 5"

Here is the code below

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
Rate = float(input("Enter Rate of Pay:"))
pay = hrs * Rate
print ("Pay:", pay)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check what `hrs` is, in particular its type. Hint: you handled the input differently on your first and second lines; how does this affect the types?

Comment: Try printing out `type(hrs)` and `type(Rate)` for a little more information.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `rate` is float but `hrs` is not. You are basically multiplying string with float. So `hrs` should be casted as float too.

```
hrs = float(input("Enter Hours:"))
Rate = float(input("Enter Rate of Pay:"))
pay = hrs * Rate
print ("Pay:, pay)
```

P.S. Have in mind PEP8 and use only lowercase for variable names unless there are const (then use upper).

Comment: To explain, the error reads "can't multiply sequence by non-int"  becase a) strings are _sequences_ of characters and b) you can multiply a sequence by an _integer number_ to chain copies of it together, eg `"a" * 3` = `"aaa"`. So Python is trying (and failing) to do that.

Comment: ahhh okay, that's perfect! Thank you very much.. That solved the problem. Is there a case where I don't use float at all in multiplication or just use float the once or will it always end up where both have to end up as a float?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable type of "hrs"

```
hrs = float(raw_input("Enter Hours:")
Rate = float(raw_input("Enter Rate of Pay:"))
pay = hrs * Rate
print ("Pay:", pay)
```

Answer (score 0):

what you're doing here is multiplying a string type with float which is resulting in the error. to fix this, you can-
`hrs = int(input("Enter Hours:")) Rate = float(input("Enter Rate of Pay:")) pay = hrs * Rate print ("Pay:", pay)`