# TypeError when trying to convert kg to lbs using input

Tags: python

I am trying to get kilograms from the user and convert them to pounds using the code below:

```py
kg = input("How many kg?")
lbs = kg * 2.2
print(lbs)
```

That code produces a following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikitalutsai/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/exercise.py", line 2, in <module>
    lbs = kg * 2.2
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I expect pounds to be converted from kg. How can i get the kilograms from the user and convert them to pounds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' on line 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64501679/typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float-on-line-5)

Comment: The "sequence" referred to in the error message is a string (str type) - i.e., the value returned from *input()*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Emilie. If you think that some answers were helpful, you can upvote them and accept them as "answers" (green mark) - that will help other users if they find this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply `string` (which you get after `input`) by `float` (2.2), you need to convert it to `float` first

```
kg = input("How many kg?")
lbs = float(kg) * 2.2
print(lbs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here
`kg=input("How many kg?")`
It is getting string input and storing in kg so the value you entered is string.
String value cannot be used for calculation so you need to convert it into float using `float()` or if you need integer you can use `int()`. In your case, you can use `kg=float(input("How many kg?"))` to get float value stored in your `kg` variable. In this case, you might get error when you input some non numerical value. You can use exception handling for that. For eg,

```
while True:
   try:
      kg=float(input("How many kg?"))
      break
   except:
      print("Please enter numerical value.")

lbs = kg * 2.2
print(lbs)
```

In the above program, I have used an infinite loop using `while True:`. To handle the exception, I have used `try` which tries to get the input and if it's correct it escapes the infinite loop by the help of `break`. And if the input is wrong it goes to `except` which can give message to user. After successfully getting input from user, program converts and gives output.

Answer (score 0):

you should put a `float` cast because `input` returns an `str`.

I would suggest you to do the following :

```py
# Read user input
kg = input("How many kg?")

# Convert and compute value
lbs = float(kg) * 2.2

# Display to the user 
print(lbs)
```

**Reference** : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input